# how to handle htaccess rewriteReule

Tags: .htaccess

i have WP site, and i have this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^mypage/    /z____articles/mypage/  [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

this makes redirection in my browser, but i dont want to redirect, i want that the page:

```
site.com/mypage/
```

showed the content of

```
site.com/z____articles/mypage/
```

i tried to use these flags `[NC,L]` or `[L]` but none of them works..

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteRule ^mypage/    /z____articles/mypage/  [L]`? Normally, this should create an internal redirect (the url displayed to the user will not change)

Comment: thanks. 
ii think, it is something wordpress problem, because when i type `/z____articles/mypage/` it doesnt work (because it is wordpress page), but if i enter a really existing folder/file, then it works as you said.

Comment: Could you please give me an other example? If you open the file directly, what url do you use? And what url do you want to be able to use once the rewrite works?